# Updating w3-import-html using JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="import" includeHTML="page.html"></div>

function getInclude() { 
    var x = document.getElementById("import").includeHTML; //returns 'undefined'
    alert(x);
}

function modInclude() { 
    document.getElementById("import").includeHTML = "page2.html"; //does nothing and FF's console outputs nothing
}
```

I'm working on a project using [W3's Import HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) and I would like to change the imported page using Javascript. No problem there, I thought it would be the same as changing the source of an image.

The syntax I tried didn't work. I did a little investigating and found out that the property itself returns 'undefined', which is a little strange considering it imports the page like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use:

```
document.getElementById("import").setAttribute("w3-include-html", "contentYouWant.html");
```

Edit: I took [w3 documentation of that w3-html-include](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) and add a simple snippet you could check to understand what is really happening. Snippet only change the attribute and alert to ensure it has been changed. Weird :'D Function is from official docs.

```html
<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<div id="inc" w3-include-html="page1.html"></div>

 <script>
includeHTML();

alert("Includes: " + document.getElementById("inc").getAttribute("w3-include-html"));
document.getElementById("inc").setAttribute("w3-include-html", "page2.html");
alert("Includes: " + document.getElementById("inc").getAttribute("w3-include-html"));
</script>
```

Cheers

Comment: This is very odd. Tried using your method, but the results are the same as in mine - nothing happens and the console logs nothing. And just to clarify, I had no trouble accessing other properties of the div.